# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mean-stack

I don't quite know where I'm going wrong with respect to dates. I am getting the error:

> "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'.  <button mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="createDamageAssessmentReport(DescOfReportInput.value, AuthorInput.value, DateInput.value)" color="primary">Create"

```html
<mat-sidenav-content>
    <div class="sect">
        <h1>Damage Assessment Report</h1>
    </div>
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header>Create report:</mat-card-header>
        <br><br>
        <mat-card-content>
            <div> 
                <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-label>Report Description</mat-label>
                    <input
                        #DescOfReportInput  
                        placeholder="Description of Report"
                        matInput type= "string"
                        required>
                </mat-form-field>
                    <br>
                <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-label>Author</mat-label>
                    <input  
                        #AuthorInput
                        placeholder="Author"
                        matInput type= "string"
                        required>
                </mat-form-field>
                <br>
                <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Date</mat-label>
                <input  
                        #DateInput
                        placeholder="----/--/--"
                        matInput type= "Date"
                        required>
                </mat-form-field>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div> 
                <button mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="createDamageAssessmentReport(DescOfReportInput.value, AuthorInput.value, DateInput.value)" color="primary">Create</button>
            </div>
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

The associated TypeScript file is as follows:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DamageAssessmentReportService } from 'src/app/damage-assessment-report.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fa-daform',
  templateUrl: './fa-daform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fa-daform.component.css']
})
export class FADAFormComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private damageAssessmentReportService : DamageAssessmentReportService) { }
  
    //assessmentDescription: string, author: string, reportDateTime: Date
  
    createDamageAssessmentReport(assessmentDescription: string, author: string, reportDateTime: Date){
        this.damageAssessmentReportService
            .createDAReport(assessmentDescription,author, reportDateTime)
            .subscribe((response : any)=>{
                console.log(response);
            });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

Comment: Your function expects a Date but you are giving a string for the last argument.

Comment: Just change `reportDateTime: Date` to `reportDateTime: string`

Comment: It works but created new problems when changing to `reportDateTime: string`

when passing that into `this.damageAssessmentReportService
            .createDAReport(assessmentDescription,author, reportDateTime)` it gives the error _Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'_ where the variable reportDateTime is placed in the function parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this:

```
createDamageAssessmentReport(assessmentDescription: string, author: string, reportDateString: string){

const reportDateTime = new Date(reportDateString); // Here you should have your date ready to be used as you wish

this.damageAssessmentReportService
   .createDAReport("New Report","Name", new Date(2020, 9, 10))
   .subscribe((response : any)=>{
                console.log(response);
   });
}
```

Comment: See [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587345/215552) for reasons why you shouldn't depend on `new Date(string)` for parsing dates.

Comment: Thxs, @Heretic Monkey, I'll take a look to it!